# I want to enqueue a .js file to my child theme

Tags: jquery, javascript

I tried to enqueue a custom .js file in my child theme directory.

In the functions.php of my child theme I find the following code

```
/* After this. you can override Accessible Zen's pluggable functions or add your own.
 * Remember, do your best to stay accessible! :)
 *
 */
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script.js', 'js/custom-script.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array( 'parent-style' ) );
}
```

where only this part was implemented by me and is supposed to load my custom.script.js from the js/ folder

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script.js', 'js/custom-script.js', array('jquery') );
```

Unfortunately it doesn't do so, can anybody help?

*Update 2

The Code looks now like this and it works, it did not work when I just added the function to the other add_action. Thanks everybody for the help! Still I wonder if there isnt a way to cut this code a little bit.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array( 'parent-style' ) );
}

/*add my custom jquery script*/
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'menu_scripts' );
function menu_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'responsive-menu', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/responsive-menu.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );
wp_enqueue_script(
    'custom-script',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-script.js',
    array( 'jquery' )
);
        }
```

What is this line for ?

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'responsive-menu', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/responsive-menu.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );
```

Is it necessary?

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script.js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'js/custom-script.js', array('jquery') );`

Comment: @Pieter I adapted your change but it is still not working.
This is what I have in my .js file and it works if I put it directly in page.php for example:
<script>
if (jQuery) {  
 
   alert("jQuery library is loaded!");
 
} else {
 
   alert("jQuery library is not found!");
 
}
</script>

Comment: @Pieter Okay I put the code in the question

Comment: Remove the script tags from your js file

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'menu_scripts' );
function menu_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'responsive-menu', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/responsive-menu.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );
wp_enqueue_script(
    'custom-script',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
    array( 'jquery' )
);
        }
```

Or like this which apparently loads faster:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

Source http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

[`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) will only work in a parent theme.

Comment: Why don't you use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`?

Comment: They both work based on my testing.

Comment: I tried the first one, it didn't work. Can you maybe post the full code blog (including my existing & working enqueues)? Because I don't know how to properly implement your code with the one that's already in my functions.php

Comment: Yes, they do, but `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` is faster :-)

Comment: Its only a working example. Some work is required on your behalf to learn how it works with your code. You can now rework your code so it loads your scripts in your theme.

Comment: @BradDalton Well I tried that but it didn't work for me. Do I have to add a second "add action" or add a second "function" or configure the "add action" or configure the "function" There are so many possibilities. If someone could briefly explain me whats best practice - or what actually works - by showing me how to implement that working example in my existing code. That would be really awesome and save me a headache

Comment: What have you tested so far? The above examples are both tested and work.

Comment: @MrKainig check in your browser console if your script is loading and if you get any jquery errors. Did you remove the script tags in your js file, as they should not be there. I cannot see that the code in this answer is not working for you. Your script should load.

Comment: @BradDalton I added the function inside my existing add_action, but that did not work. When I copied the working example 1:1 beneath my existing add action it worked flawless.

The post was updated once again. Thanks guys :)

Comment: Thanks for the part "get_template_directory_uri() will only work in a parent theme." It gives me headache for a couple of days

Comment: the second method perfectly works for me by just changing `custom-script` to `parent-script`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your handles! The script can fail to load if you pick a handle that has been used elsewhere. If all looks correct with no errors but no script load, check the installation for something else using the same handle.

In my case, as I'm extending a parent via a child theme, I (stupidly in hindsight!) stuck with the same naming convention of the parent. Lesson learnt!

Answer (score 1):

I usually make it like that:

Go to the child theme

1. create js folder inside child theme
2. create script.js file inside js folder

and then paste this code inside script.js file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts', 10 );
function custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_javascript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
}
```