# How to add JavaScript file using wp_enqueue_scripts?

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I have made a very simple JavaScript script. There is 1 `.js` file with a lot of code, and in the HTML file there is only 2 lines. The script works fine when I test it on a plain HTML page, but when I try it with WordPress, it doesn't work.

I guess it has something to do with the path to the external `.js` file (`src="js/file.js"`).

What am I missing? Why isn't my script loading correctly?

Edit: See comment to answer below, I have now added the code to the `functions.php`, but still not working.

Edit2: This is the code I use in the `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_front_scripts' );
function my_enqueue_front_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/file.js' );
}
```

And this is the code in my head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> url_detect.OnBack = function() { window.location.replace("URL.org"); } </script>
```

Comment: How are you calling to script?  Specifically, are you declaring it directly in **header.php** (the wrong way) or using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook and adding it via a function? Please update your question to include more details.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to load your script as an EDIT to your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to enqueue a .js file to my child theme](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177157/i-want-to-enqueue-a-js-file-to-my-child-theme)

Comment: If will edit, but I use the code posted below:

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_front_scripts');
function my_enqueue_front_scripts(){

    wp_enqueue_script('my-custom-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/file.js');

}

Comment: Do you have wp_head() in your header.php file?

Comment: Yes, i does  the wp_head() in the header.php

Comment: First of all, Please check whether your `file.js` and `custom script` are inserted in your page by viewing the page source.

Comment: @Alex Was my answer helpful to you?! Please accept and upvote if it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress you should enqueue your scripts (and styles) using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook.

The main reason for this is to ensure that your script/style is only added once. You can, if you wish, aslo add conditions so that a script/style is only added to certain pages.

You say in your question that your script is located at **js/file.js** - presumabily this is within your Theme?

If so, try the code below (place it in **functions.php**), if not, please provide further details.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_front_scripts');
function my_enqueue_front_scripts(){

    wp_enqueue_script('my-custom-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/file.js');

}
```

Note that dispite the name, this action hook should also be used to enqueue your style sheets. For more information, please take some time to view the pages below -

- [`wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)

  - [`wp_enqueue_script` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)
  - [`wp_enqueue_style` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

Comment: I did what you said and added the code into function.php, the only code I got now in my head tag is this.

<script type="text/javascript">
 url_detect.OnBack = function()
 {
 window.location.replace("http://URL.org");
 }
 </script>

Still not working.

Comment: Lol, someone has just seen fit to vote this answer down, yet they don't have the good grace to say why they feel it deserves a down vote.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `file.js` version is `1.0` and you want the js to be loaded to the document head (instead of footer), and according to the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) You may add script files to your document using:

Active theme's **functions.php**

```
function my_add_js(){
    $theme_uri = get_template_directory_uri();
    wp_enqueue_script( $handle,  $theme_uri . '/js/file.js', array(), '1.0', false );
}
```

while adding it on an action to take place:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_add_js' );
```

Active theme's **header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    <!-- other head section stuff here ... -->

    wp_head();?>
    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- some other html stuff maybe here ... -->
```

### Note

If you have a JavaScript snippet and wanted to add it to you footer using your theme's functions.php file:

```
function my_add_js(){
    ?>
    <script>
    // This is my script ...
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_add_js' );
```